# What is the best way to add comments to multi-line quoted words?

Tags: perl

The starting point:

```
my @array=qw(word1 word2 word3);
```

Now I want to put each word on a separate line:

```
my @array=qw(
   word1
   word2
   word3
);
```

Now I want to add comments:

```
my @array=qw(
   word1 # This is word1
   word2 # This is word2
   word3 # This is word3
);
```

The above of course does not work and generates warnings with *use warnings*.

So, what is the best way to create an array out of a commented list like the above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend avoiding `qw`.

```
my @array = (
   'word1',  # This is word1
   'word2',  # This is word2
   'word3',  # This is word3
);
```

But you could use [Syntax::Feature::QwComments](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Syntax::Feature::QwComments).

```
use syntax qw( qw_comments );

my @array = qw(
   word1  # This is word1
   word2  # This is word2
   word3  # This is word3
);
```

Or parse it yourself.

```
sub myqw { $_[0] =~ s/#[^\n]*//rg =~ /\S+/g }

my @array = myqw(q(
   word1  # This is word1
   word2  # This is word2
   word3  # This is word3
));
```